# Ensuring static singletons create their instance on startup

Tags: c#

I have an abstract class (`Saveable<T>`) whose children all act as an instance of a saveable file. These children are essentially singletons, so their instance is set by

```
static T _instance = new()
```

In their static constructor, they do their initial file load as described below:

For example, I might have `UserSettings : Saveable<UserSettings>` which, on Application startup, should load `UserSettings.json` and set the instance to the deserialized data.

This is all working as intended, but this is the problem:

`UserSettings` in this case will only instantiate `_instance` and therefore read `UserSettings.json` on the first call to it, because of course that's how static classes work & I just didn't remember. This creates some unwanted delays near the beginning of the application launch each time a `Saveable` is referenced for the first time, and I would prefer they all read their files during the initial load.

Is there a way to do this? I've thought about making an Attribute and manually loading them as a part of the bootstrapper, but I'd prefer not to have to do this for each Saveable. I can also go through the assemblies and laod each class that inherits `Saveable`, but I was wondering if there was a better solution than using Reflection?

Comment: intersting , you want anti-lazy. I think you have to reflect, it should not be that much code

Comment: Make them lazy in the normal fashion.  Then, make the very first class you have in your code (the class that includes `Main`) have a static constructor (i.e., that will run before `Main` runs) and have that static constructor reference all the types you want to have aggressively constructed).

Comment: You can explicitly force static constructors to run with something like; `RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor(typeof(UserSettings).TypeHandle);`

Comment: @JeremyLakeman interesting! I might use this in conjunction with reflection & inherited attributes to target all the classes I want to 'Wake up'

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way that you can tell the runtime to pre-init static fields. The only option I'm aware of is to use reflection:

```
var types = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Saveable<>))
        .GetTypes()
        .Where(x => 
               x.IsClass && 
               x.BaseType != null && 
               x.BaseType.IsGenericType && 
               x.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Saveable<>))
        .ToList();

foreach (var t in types)
{
    var x = t.BaseType.GetField("_instance", 
                BindingFlags.Instance | 
                BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
                BindingFlags.Static);

    if (x != null)
    {
        var val = x.GetValue(null); // this is what forces the initialization
    }
}
```